# Query where array of object does not contain property equal to string value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Given the following document, how can I query for a document where `meta` does not contain an object with a specific name?

```
{ "_id" : 1, "meta" : [ { "name" : "alpha", "date" : ISODate("2015-09-08T19:51:03.275Z") } ] }
```

I'm looking for the opposite of this:

```
db.content.find({'meta.name': 'alpha'})
```

I want to query for the same document like this:

```
Find me the document where 'meta.name' !== 'beta'.
```

Comment: I can't get `$in` or `$nin` to work with this example.

Comment: Related: [To $nin or not to $nin](https://snakierten96.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/to-nin-or-not-to-nin/) as you seem to misconceive that you need such operators when working with arrays as that post discusses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 db.content.find({'meta.name': {$ne: "beta"}})
```

since `$ne` works for nested arrays too

Answer (score 0):

Came through few such questions previously.Assuming your collection as 'test'. Try this instead

db.test.find({"_id":1, "meta":{$elemMatch :{"name":{$ne:"beta"}}}});